# OnTouchListener not called

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying to start voice recognition on a touch but the issue is OnTouchListener is not called when user touches the screen

I tried to put breakpoint in function but it does not come in function at all

On my laptop the Logcat is not working so I cant use log and thus using a toast to see if the function is called.

Code is as below. can anyone please help why this function is not called on touch??

Updated:

I am calling setOnTouchListener in OnCreate and now after using view my application is crashing on startup.

```
View view = findViewById(R.layout.voice_recog);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Touch recognised",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I found that the issue is regarding assigning the view...Application is crashing because of source not found error...on line

```
    View view = findViewById(R.layout.voice_recog);
    //crashes on below line ....with Source not found error
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
```

Comment: Where do you call `setOnTouchListener`?

Comment: Are you making sure to add the listener to the containing View?

Comment: @oakleaf: I am calling it in OnCreate...
I have updated the code and View is assigned to setOnTouchListener

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you haven't assigned the listener to any View, seeing as you just create the listener here. Use `findViewById()` to get an instance of whichever View you want to run this code on, and then call:

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(TouchListener);
```

Comment: thanx but application is crashing on load only
    View view = findViewById(R.layout.voice_recog);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Touch recognised",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        
    return false;
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onCreate:

```
getView().setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener);
```

Comment: Nope @TronicZoneB not working....OnCreate is not able to find the getView function...I tried this also but did not help

Comment: Oh ok, try the onStart. Thats actually where I call mine but I wasn't sure if that was convention or not, it's just what worked for my situation, thus why I initially said onCreate, but you could try your onStart, after creating the new `onTouchListener`